# Al leer una lista desde un archivo, tengo un error con en la ultima linea. no se como solucionarlo

Tags: smalltalk

```
leer: unaLista desde: unArchivo 
| dataStream bos array |

dataStream := unArchivo asFilename readStream.
bos := BinaryObjectStorage onOldNoScan: dataStream.
[array := bos contents] ensure: [bos close].
```

**`unaLista nextPutAll: array.  <-- en esta linea me salta el error.`**

Answer (score 0):

Si saber cuál es el mensaje de error, solamente puedo inferir que `unaLista` es una collección y por lo tanto no comprende `nextPutAll:` ya que este mensaje lo entienden los streams de escritura, no las collecciones.

Si `unaLista` es una `OrderedCollection`, tendrías que reemplazar `nextPutAll:` por `addAll:`.